# SQL: How to ORDER BY variables - by specific vars and not by content as it automatically does

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM prods 
        JOIN keywords
            ON prods.prod_id = keywords.key_prod
        JOIN data 
            ON keywords.key_id = data.dat_id
        WHERE 
               prods.prod_id = '$id' AND data.dat_date = '$date1'
            OR prods.prod_id = '$id' AND data.dat_date = '$date2'
            OR prods.prod_id = '$id' AND data.dat_date = '$date3'
        ORDER BY kay_country ASC,
                 key_id ASC, 
                 dat_date ASC
```

and I want it to order $date1, $date2, $date3 by this order in the result list, although $date3 is bigger than $date1.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set()`.  However, with dates, that might be tricky.  So, instead, use `case`:

```
order by key_country, key_id,
         (case when data.dat_date = '$date1' then 1
               when data.dat_date = '$date2' then 2
               when data.dat_date = '$date3' then 3
          end)
```

The `find_in_set()` version is:

```
order by key_country, key_id,
         find_in_set(data.dat_date, '$date1', '$date2', '$date3')
```

Comment: I don't understand how this can be inserted in my query

Comment: Tried this and this didn't work: 

`SELECT * FROM prods JOIN keywords ON prods.prod_id = keywords.key_prod JOIN data ON keywords.key_id = data.dat_id WHERE prods.prod_id = '6' AND data.dat_date = '2016-03-15' OR prods.prod_id = '6' AND data.dat_date = '2016-03-08' OR prods.prod_id = '6' AND data.dat_date = '2016-03-07' ORDER BY kay_country, (case when data.dat_date = '$date1' then 1 when data.dat_date = '$date2' then 2 when data.dat_date = '$date3' then 3 end), key_id ASC, dat_date ASC`